# Check whether the set is connected or compact?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $ f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ defined as:

$$A = \bigl\{\, y\in \mathbb{R} :y= \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)\text{, for  some  sequence  $x_n \rightarrow \infty$}\,\bigr\}.$$
Then the set $A$ is necessarily connected? compact? a singleton set?

Clearly, choosing $f(x)=\sin(x)$ implies $A=[-1,1]$. Hence $A$ need not be a singleton set. Intuitively it seems $A$ should be a connected set. But I am unable to produce a proof.

Comment: Is this set closed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $a,b \in A$, say $f(a_n)\to a$, $f(b_n)\to b$ with $a_n,b_n\to\infty$. Wlog. $a>b$. Let $c\in(a,b)$. For almost all $n$, we have $f(a_n)>c>f(b_n)$. By the IVT, there exists $c_n$ between $a_n$ and $b_n$ with $f(c_n)=c$. Then $c_n\to\infty$, which shows $c\in A$. We conclude that $A$ is convex, hence connected.

$A$ need not be compact, consider $f(x)=x\sin x$.

Comment: Your choice is incorrect.  If $a>b$ then $c\in (b,a)$.